# Tools for automating SilverLight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, automation, ui-automation

I want to automate the application develoepd in silverlight. Can you let me know whether there are any open source tools are available which can be used for automating SilverLight app. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "to automate the application develoepd in silverlight"?

Comment: I'm still confused by the question :(

Comment: We are trying to perform UI automation of an application developed in SilverLight and for the same we are searching for tool/libraries which will help us for the same. While searching; so far I came across Watir, Selenium, WebAii, UIA tools using which we can be able to automate the SilverLight apps and am evaluating which one is more suitable for us. 
On similiar lines I am also looking for suggestions if anyone else has tried automating SilverLight UI using any other tool and what are their experiences with that tool.

Answer (score 3):

We are doing UI testing on a Silverlight application using the [UIAutomation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx), and it works very nicely.

[Project White](http://www.codeplex.com/white) is a library that sits on top of UIAutomation, and many people find it helpful. I prefer to use the UIAutomation APIs directly - it's really not as hard as you might think, as [my tutorial](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html) shows.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, Per my understanding project white retrieves the controls based on Name/Class/Type/ID but in application which we are automating there are quiet a few controls which does not have any of the above property set by dev team. Can you please let me know if there is any way using which we would be able to automate such controls using project white. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to perform User Interface Automation (UIA) to simulate mouse clicks, keyboard presses, etc. there is no "easy" way to get this today.

I've seen some third party tools that may work, such as [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools.aspx). Note that I have not used and do not endorse this, just know it is out there!

Comment: Can you please mention which third party tools are available for same

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying out Project White and finding it quite easy to use.

Before using Project White I tried out [WiPFlash](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/) which was also rather easy to use.  It just lacked a few features that I was after (Right Click and Drag options).